# Putting a dictionary inside a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

Lets say we have

{'Pop': 5}

and we have a variable

a = 'store'

how could I get the output:

{'store': {'pop': 5}}

Is there a easy way?

Comment: How about typing it in?

Comment: Trying to make a function that does this, but I don't know if there is a way to do it normally. I thought I could maybe do it by letting dict1 = {'pop': 5}, then doing dict2['store'] = dict1. Didnt work though because if I wanted to add more outputs it would take the last inputed one

Comment: are you sure that didnt work? a = dict(), b= {'pop' : 5}; a['store'] = b

Comment: oh ur right that does work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dict1 = {'pop': 5}
dict2 = {'store': dict1}
print(dict2)
```

This will work. If you tried to do `dict2['store'] = dict1` immediately, it wouldn't have worked, because dict2 needs to exist before you can say "put stuff in dict2". An alternate approach would have been:

```
dict1 = {'pop': 5}
dict2 = {}    # making an empty dictionary
dict2['store'] = dict1    # now we can put stuff in it
print(dict2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put a dictionary inside a dictionary.

Try it:

`print({a:{'pop':5}})`

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple.  You can even assign values normally.

```
print({'store': {'pop': 5}})

temp = {}
temp['score']  = {'pop':5}
print(temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your best option is,

```
a = 'store'
temp = {}
temp[a] = {'Pop': 5}

print(temp)
```

regards!